# Laravel - Send mail and pass multi array data

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

The end result I'm aiming for (if it's possible):

To iterate thru all `$users` and their `$properties`, grab the property address and then iterate thru `$complaints` (complaint belong to property) and create `<table>` for each property with it's complaints, it is possible that a property will not have complaints so need to check for that too.

I did try this code and managed to put all the $data in an array but first I can not iterate it in the email view and second if i'll have 1000 properties and each property will have 30 complaints... you get the idea... no good...

```
$users = User::all()->toArray();

foreach ($users as $user)
{
    $report = [];
    $properties = Property::where('user_id', $user['id'])->get()->toArray();

    array_set($report, 'user', $user);

    foreach ($properties as $property)
    {
        array_set($report, 'properties', $property);

        $complaints = Complaint::where('property_id', $property['id'])->where('status', 'ACT')->get()->toArray();

        foreach ($complaints as $complaint)
        {
            array_set($report, 'complaints', $complaint);
        }
    }
    Mail::queue('emails.reports.weekly', $report, function($message) {
        $message->to($report['user']['email'])->subject('Weekly Report');
    });
}
```

Comment: if your are concern with runtime then you could eagerload the data. this link will help you http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: I know that but I can not pass a collection to the email and iterate it there.

Comment: then generate the whole `html` and pass it..